# Extension to trigger a search function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just have a theoretical question.

I would like to develop an extension that creates a search with a defined number (GTIN) in the following page:

https://www.gs1us.org/tools/gs1-company-database-gepir/home/gtinsearch

The search would be of a GTIN number.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Maybe some extension that triggers the vm.search() function with the GTIN value inside?

Comment: You need to inject a content script. Read this doc:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference,

Comment: I read it twice, probably this is far beyond my programming skils, as I still do not know how to do it. If you could provide any other pointer that would be awesome. Otherwise, thanks a lot, will keep on researching